# voting in all fields before submit results

Tags: 7, entities, rating

I have a content type (computer) with multiple [rate fields](https://drupal.org/project/rate) (performance, battery range, price, ...) type fivestars. By default, the module sends the results by ajax whenever you click on a star; what I need is that you vote in all fields, before the results are sent (with a button).

Is it possible to do this? And how?

Comment: What details are you looking for? The only answer in your question is whether this is possible, and that's what the answer is about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually Berliner was right. To achieve this functionality you need to override the rate module JavaScript.

Below is the code/steps to achieve the same.

1. Create you own module to override the rate module, never touch core/contrib. Let's take our custom module name as `rate_custom`. This is the info file (`rate_custom.info`):

```
name = Custom Rate module
description = Custom module to override Rate module
core = 7.x
package = Voting
dependencies[] = votingapi
dependencies[] = rate
files[] = rate_custom.module
version = "7.x-1.0"
core = "7.x"
```

2. Add the button to the rate widgets to submit their result using hook_node_view in our custom module (`rate_custom.module`) like this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_view().
 */
function rate_custom_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode = '') {
  if ($view_mode != 'rss') {  
    // Adding the button to the node view
    $widgets = rate_get_active_widgets('node', $node->type, $view_mode);
    if (!empty($widgets)) {
      $widget_code = array(
        '#weight' => 51,
        '#markup' => '<button class="rate-submit-button">'. t('Submit Rating') . '</button>',
        '#type' => 'item',
      );
      $node->content['rate_submit_button'] = $widget_code;
      drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module', 'rate_custom') . '/rate_custom.js');
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'rate_custom') . '/rate_custom.css');
    }
  }
}
```

3. Now override rate module's rate submission calls JavaScript in separate JavaScript file (`rate_custom.js`) within our module. Below is the complete code.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.rate_custom = {
    attach: function(context) {
      // Bind the click event to our submit button.
      Drupal.rateTrack = {};
      $('.rate-submit-button').die('click').live('click', function() {
        var $node = $(this).parents('div.node');
        // Prevent empy submission.
        if (typeof Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')] === 'undefined' || $.isEmptyObject(Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')])) {
          alert(Drupal.t('Please rate before submit.'));
          return false;
        }
        // Trigger the saved ratings one by one.
        for (var idx in Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')]) {
          var widget = Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')][idx].widget;
          var data = Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')][idx].data;
          var token = Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')][idx].token;
          Drupal.rateVote_old(widget, data, token);
        }
        // Empty the tracking variable.
        Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')] = {};
      });
      // Overriding the rate module's CSS to indicate currently rated result.
      $('.rate-button').die('mousedown').live('mousedown', function() {
        jQuery(this).parent('li').nextAll().find('.rate-button').removeClass('rate-fivestar-mark-filled rate-fivestar-btn-filled').addClass('rate-fivestar-mark-empty');
        jQuery(this).parent('li').prevAll().andSelf().find('.rate-button').removeClass('rate-fivestar-mark-empty').addClass('rate-fivestar-mark-filled rate-fivestar-btn-filled')
      });
    }
  };
    
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Re-declare the rateVote function and assign the original function to another variable.
    Drupal.rateVote_old = Drupal.rateVote;
    Drupal.rateVote = function(widget, data, token) {
      var $node = $(widget).parents('div.node');
      // Fallback to original immediate ajax submission, if we're unable to find the rating
      // submit button for the current node.
      if ($node.find('.rate-submit-button').length) {
        if (typeof Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')] === 'undefined') {
          Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')] = {};
        }
        // Store the rating in the local variable by node and rate widget, so that user can
        // rate multiple nodes and modify their votes.
        Drupal.rateTrack[$node.attr('id')][$(widget).attr('id')] = {
          widget: widget,
          data: data,
          token: token
        };
        $(".rate-info", widget).text(Drupal.t('Please submit the rating to save it!'));
        return false;
      }
      else {
        return Drupal.rateVote_old(widget, data, token);
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

4. Add the custom CSS (`rate_custom.css`) to override the rate module's CSS to indicate current result (Adjust the file paths as per your configuration).

```
.rate-fivestar-mark-filled {
  background: url("/sites/all/custom/modules/rate/templates/fivestar/fivestar.png") no-repeat 0 -16px !important;
}

.rate-fivestar-mark-empty {
  background: url("/sites/all/custom/modules/rate/templates/fivestar/fivestar.png") no-repeat 0 -32px !important;
}
```

Finally we're done with it, just go and enable your module. Now unless you click on "Submit Rating" your rating won't get submitted.

Note: I wrote this for the fivestar widget alone. Also check all the possible scenarios.

Comment: thanks for your reply. when I get home I see in more detail and say something.

Comment: I've been testing your code and found a small bug. when a node has several fivestar widgets, widget and simply vote by pressing the button, the system sends the evaluation. What I needed is that the user was required to vote on all fivestar widgets before submitting reviews.

Comment: Then add the validation in the $('.rate-submit-button') click handler. i.e check whether Drupal.rateTrack object length is equals to the no of widgets in the node.

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can think of to do this is to override the javascript function `Drupal.rateVote` which is declared in the file `rate.js`. It would require considerable work to achieve what you want.

You can have a look at [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11823/how-to-override-a-js-function-in-the-media-module-without-editing-the-actual-mod/11831#11831) where someone else had to override a javascript function from a contrib module.